# Is it possible to have open source software such that binaries can only be distributed by the official builder?

Tags: android

I want to build an Android ROM for myself and the ROM i picked has an "official maintainer". On the website it states that if a device has an "official maintainer", it is forbidden to share an "unofficial build". If someone builds and shares it, they will send a dmca request. is that possible with open source software?

Comment: Forbidden to share at all, or just forbidden to share on that website?

Comment: Does the ROM include the (GPLv2-licensed) Linux kernel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not according to the definition of *open source* we use here, which is [the OSI's](https://opensource.org/osd).  That requires that

> The license shall not restrict any party from selling or giving away the software

and that

> The license must allow modifications and derived works, and must allow them to be distributed under the same terms as the license of the original software

So if I can't modify the program to make my own "*unofficial build*", and then share it, we don't consider the software to be open source.  That said, the term "*open source*" isn't a restricted one, so anyone can distribute their software under any old hideous proprietary licence and yet claim it's "*open source*".   They can even start DMCA takedowns for violation of their proprietary licence, and still claim with a straight face that their software is open source.  To my mind, they're wrong, and their claim is a lie, but they're not forbidden from making it.

However, the idea that you can restrict the use of a trademarked name is much more normal, and acceptable within the free software community.  So a site that said, eg, "*we distribute the official build of FooBarOS<sup>TM</sup> for the Google BazBar Developer Phone; if you distribute your own build for this phone, you must not call it FooBarOS*" is fine.

Comment: Apparently, there is also a DMCA Takedown procedure for trademark violations.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I did not know that!  Thank you!